# JS Function call after XMLHttpRequest a PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

i click on a button that calls a PHP File over a XMLHttpRequest.

In this PHP File a write a new Javascript Function.

The Result of the PHP File is then loaded on a div container on my first page from where a have clicked the button.

If i click then another button to call the new written Js Function i have no results.
(Maybe it isn't defined on that page because of the XMLHttpRequested PHP File)

How can i write this function over a XMLHttpRequested PHP File and call after that this function ???

Thank You for help !!!

here the code from first page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function createfunc()
      {
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
        RNG_Option = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
      else
        {
        RNG_Option = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
      RNG_Option.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if(RNG_Option.readyState==4 && RNG_Option.status==200)    
          {       
      document.getElementById("phprequest").innerHTML=RNG_Option.responseText;
          }    
        }
      RNG_Option.open("GET","create.php", true);
      RNG_Option.send();
      }         
    </script>       
  </head>    
   
  <body>
    <a onclick="createfunc();">Create Function</a>
    <div id="phprequest"></div>
    <a onclick="callfunc();">Call Function</a>  
  </body>
</html>
```

the php file create.php :

```
<?php   
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";   
echo "function callfunc()";    
echo "{";   
echo "alert('CALL MY FUNCTION');";   
echo "}";   
echo "</script>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us some relevant code , in particular how you process this function text when you receive it. For reference take a few minutes to read through [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score -1):

I am using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for ajax request.

**temp.php:**

```
<?php
echo "function callfunc()";
echo "{";
echo "alert('CALL MY FUNCTION');";
echo "}";
```

**test.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <a onclick="createfunc();">Create Function</a>
    <div id="phprequest"></div>
    <a onclick="callfunc();">Call Function</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createfunc() {
            fetch('temp.php')
                .then(res => res.text()
                    .then(data => {
                        let script_tag = document.createElement('script');
                        script_tag.type = 'text/javascript';
                        script_tag.text = data;
                        // document.body.appendChild(script_tag);
                        document.querySelector('#phprequest').appendChild(script_tag);
                    }));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to add JS to current page, you need to get that JS as text, create a `script` element, add that JS to `script` element and then add that `script` element to your page's body or into desired element.